# How to keep all the islands facing the right direction (UV)?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am looking to make all the island facing the correct way. I can use a texture with arrows to help me, but it will be difficult to notice the small mistakes. How can I have the islands all facing the correct direction?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. What are your islands? How do you want to position them? By facing do you mean "all upwards" or rather "same rotation around Z axis"? Maybe add a screenshot?

Comment: Not in UV unwrapping's nature to maintain "direction" of your 3d view as much as filling up the 2d space while minimising stretch. I'd suggest unwrapping each island with Project from view, always with the right side "up". Cube projection or Follow active quads can also sometimes happen to project everything right-side up, depending on your mesh. Does the UV map need to be that exact that rotation by-eye (zoomed in) won't suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3D-View-Window press N for opening Properties.

Under "Mesh Display" you find "NORMALS:" press the "Face" Symbol. If you now go with your mesh to the Edit-Mode you see little lines coming out of the center of each face (These lines show the Normal direction). With "Size" in Properties-Panel you can change the Length of the these lines.

Now choose all your faces and open Tool-Shelf by pressing "T". Under "Shading" you find "Recalculate". All Faces should now look in the same Direction. If any of your faces should not, select these faces manually and press "Flip Direction".

"Recalculate" could not work perfectly when your faces are not connected (Island-faces?????)